# Children's book in a fantasy world

Tags: story-identification, books, childrens-novel

I'm pretty sure that this book is the last of a series. I only read the beginning.Based on the back-cover description, the story is set in another world that is populated by fantastic creatures. For some reason, I think the world is called "Neverland" or something that ends in "-land", but it's not a Peter Pan book. What I do remember is that there is a scene where a tribe or nation of fantasy creatures is invaded by another faction. The tribe that is being invaded is prone to entering a trance-like state when they see metal glinting, which is weaponized by their invaders (They carry poles that have bits of metal tied to them). The defenders try to resist the effects of metal glinting, but to no avail. That's pretty much everything I remember about this book. Any ideas what it is?

Other information that I think I remember about the book, but can't be considered reliable:
There is some tree that is apparently considered important.
The main character leaves that world to either go into what is considered the real world or some other world, either temporarily or permanently.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This sounds like the first book in the "[The Neverland Wars](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/27396942-the-neverland-wars)" series by Audrey Greathouse. It is the first in a four book series. In it, there's a magical realm called Neverland which is populated by creatures like faeries, giants, and trolls. The main character is a human girl named Gwen, who is from the human world, and gets sent to Neverland. The human world invades Neverland and Gwen must fight against them and save the magical realm from destruction. The invaders use glinting metal to hypnotize the magical creatures, which the defenders must find a way to resist. There is a mysterious tree called the "Tree of Wishes" which plays a part in the story.

It does take place in the Peter Pan universe (though later on than the first book) but it matches your plot description perfectly.